# Trouble constraining one database table to another

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL and trying to learn how to reference on table to another. This is what I have:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS itemData (
  id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  title varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  sector_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  status_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  locations_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  payments_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  type_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sector_id` FOREIGN KEY (sector_id) REFERENCES `sector` (`sector_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_status_id` FOREIGN KEY (`status_id`) REFERENCES `status` (`status_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_locations_id` FOREIGN KEY (`locations_id`) REFERENCES `location` (`locations_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_payments_id` FOREIGN KEY (`payments_id`) REFERENCES `payments` (`payments_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_type_id` FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `type` (`type_id`) 
);
```

Then I have my reference table for example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS itemStatus (
  id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY
);
```

This doesn't seem to validate, can someone tell me where I have gone wrong please?

Comment: What error do you get? And how are those two tables related anyway?

Comment: You can't reference a table that not exists. So you've got to create your tables in the right order. Before you can create this table you've got to create the tables `sector`, `status`, `location`, `payments`, `type` with the appropriate named and indexed columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to change your table definition like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS itemStatus (
  status_id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY
);
```

as the constraint definition in your table is like this:

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_status_id` FOREIGN KEY (`status_id`) REFERENCES `itemstatus` (`status_id`),
```

You need to update the correct table in the constraint.

Also if you dont want to change the table definition then change the constraint like this:

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `itemstatus` (`id`)
```

Comment: @James Willson:- Do note that you are having the incorrect name if the table which you are trying to reference. So you need to correct that as well. :)

Comment: But it doesn't seem like there is anything to reference the reference row i.e (sector_id)

Comment: @JamesWillson:- Do you have a `sector` table? As you are referencing the sector_id as foreign key

Comment: @JamesWillson:- You are referencing 5 foreign keys. I assume that you have the id of those in the respective tables. else it would throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_status_id` FOREIGN KEY (`status_id`) REFERENCES `status` (`status_id`)
```

Here's the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS itemStatus (
  id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY
);
```

There's no column named `status_id` in that table.

Either rename the primary key column to `status_id` or change the constraint to point to `id`.

Comment: and it's not the table `status` but the table `itemStatus` too, so I would assume changing the constraint to the existing tables would be better.

Comment: Which constraint do I change, assuming i keep it as ID. ```CONSTRAINT `fk_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `status` (`id`)```?